# How to replace multiple independent values using QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, replace

I have a vector with different land use classes for which I want to add labels that correspond to their number. I am trying to use to QGIS field calculator, I have the code to replace one value into a new column, but I want to do it for all the independent variables. My code however seems incorrect and the label name doesn't change to what I want it to be. I have a total of six values that need a new label. I am using the code

> replace("land_classes", '6', 'type 1')
> +
> replace("land_classes", '7', 'type 2')

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to use a CASE statement Like so :

```
CASE
  WHEN "land_classes"='6' THEN 'type 1'
  WHEN "land_classes"='7' THEN 'type 2'
  ...
  ...
  ELSE 'Not a valid land use class'
END
```

Note that I assume that the "land_classes" is a text field so the value are between quote (as you did in your expression), if the "land_classes" field is rather a numeric field (by your picture that seem likely) you should not use quote around the value (so change ='6' to =6 ).

Also made sure to set the output field to string type.

Comment: Thanks J.R. this did exactly the trick